# VBA string with milliseconds to date

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I have a string in the form `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm"` (where the end is milliseconds)

I'd like to convert it to a number, preferably a `Date`, which preserves all the information

I've tried `CDate()`, eg.

```
Dim dateValue As Date
dateValue = CDate("2017-12-23 10:29:15.223")
```

But get a type mismatch error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB6 Date data type: precision and formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186622/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsecond support for VT_DATE type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3987079/11683)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Date` type holds the number of days since `December 30 1899` with a precision of one second. Though it's still possible to hold the milliseconds by storing the date in a currency type since it can hold 4 extra digits compared to a Date/Double.

So an alternative would be to store the date as a timestamp in a `Currency` type representing the number of seconds since `December 30 1899`:

```
Public Function CDateEx(text As String) As Currency
    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(text, ".")
    CDateEx = CCur(CDate(parts(0)) * 86400) + CCur(parts(1) / 1000)
End Function
```

And to convert the timestamp back to a string:

```
Public Function FormatDateEx(dt As Currency) As String
    FormatDateEx = Format(dt / 86400, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss") & "." & ((dt - Fix(dt)) * 1000)
End Function
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks Michael. Although I think there is a minor bug in FormatDateEx. I believe you need FormatDateEx = Format( *Fix*(dt) /86400, ..... Try testing with FormatDateEx(CDateEx("15:59:58.921")). Without the fix the seconds become 59, not 58 (In Excel 2016 64 bit windows). I have not thoroughly tested this so be careful.

Comment: Last part of FormatDateEx should be "& Format(((dt - Fix(dt)) * 1000),"000") or 74 would be .74 and not .074

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Left$` function to trim the decimal point and milliseconds:

```
Dim dateValue As Date
dateValue = CDate(Left$("2017-12-23 10:29:15.223", 19))
```

Comment: UpVoting because, with the understanding that the Date data type has resolution to seconds, this is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code below contains all the components you might need to manage your dates and their milliseconds.

```
Private Sub ParseTime()

    Dim strTime As String
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim Dt As Double

    strTime = "2017-12-23 10:29:15.221"
    Sp = Split(strTime, ".")
    strTime = Sp(0)

    Dt = CDbl(CDate(strTime))
    strTime = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
    If UBound(Sp) Then
        Dt = Dt + CDbl(Sp(1)) * 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / (10 ^ Len(Sp(1)))
        strTime = strTime & "." & CInt(Sp(1))
    End If
    Debug.Print Format(Dt, strTime)
End Sub
```

I can't say that I am entirely happy with the solution because the print is only implicitly equal to the date value. However, I found that the formerly valid Date/Time format, like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000", doesn't seem to work since 2007. However, it should be possible to prove conclusively that the Date/Time value is equal to its rendering by the format mask I includedcd above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DateAdd to add the last 0.233 seconds after obtaining the whole second as a date Value?

```
Dim Str As String, MS As String
Dim DateValue As Date
Dim L as Integer
Str = "2017-12-23 10:29:15.223"
For L = 1 to Len(Str)
    If Left(Right(Str, L), 1) = "." Then
        MS = "0" & Right(Str, L)
        Str = Left(Str, Len(Str) - L)
        Exit For
    End If
Next L
DateValue = CDate(Str)
If MS <> "" Then DateValue = DateAdd("S",MS,DateValue)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as other answers have highlighted, it is the `Date` datatype that's the problem; it does not hold numbers to ms precision. So `DateAdd` has no effect, as the decimal portion of the date is cut off. You can test this with a `debug.print DateValue` before and after the `DateAdd`

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer has an error (as spotted by Jim) when the decimal part rounds up.

The following corrects the error (slightly modified for tenths of seconds rather than milliseconds and with a parameterized format pattern).

```
Public Function FormatDateEx(dt As Currency, formatPattern As String) As String
    Rem FormatDateEx = Format(dt / 86400, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss") & "." & ((dt - Fix(dt)) * 1000)
    Dim decimalPart As Double
    decimalPart = Round(((dt - Fix(dt)) * 10), 0)
    If (decimalPart = 10) Then
        FormatDateEx = format(dt / 86400, formatPattern) & ".0"
    Else
        FormatDateEx = format(Fix(dt) / 86400, formatPattern) & "." & decimalPart
    End If
End Function
```