# How to update the image before sleep?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move a picture and then make the code sleep for a while. The problem is, the position of the picture does not update before "sleeping". Here is the code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture1").IncrementLeft 100
Sleep 500
```

When I execute this code(the sub is called by a button), the position of the picture does not change until the end of "sleep 500".

How can I update the picture before sleep? I will be much appreciated if you can also explain this to me.

---

Update using DoEvents:
I created a new excel file, with only the picture and button in the sheet, and the following code(full code):

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
Sub Button1_Click()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture 2").IncrementLeft 100
DoEvents
Sleep 2000
End Sub
```

and it still doesn't work. Or did I misunderstood the usage of "DoEvents"? I apologize if I am being stupid.

---

Update using GetTickCount and suggestion from braX: I am using another WinAPI GetTickCount to serve as timer for DoEvent loop. Now it seems to work with smaller time interval?

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub Button1_Click()
Move_Right_With_Time "Sheet1", "Picture1", 50, 100
Move_Right_With_Time "Sheet1", "Picture1", 80, 200
Move_Right_With_Time "Sheet1", "Picture1", 300, 300
Move_Right_With_Time "Sheet1", "Picture1", 20, 400
End Sub

'time_gap represent the time slept after moving
Sub Move_Right_With_Time(worksheet As String, shape As String, time_gap As Long, distance As Double)
Dim start_timer As Long

Worksheets(worksheet).Shapes(shape).IncrementLeft distance

start_timer = GetTickCount
While GetTickCount < start_timer + time_gap
DoEvents
Wend

Sleep time_gap

End Sub
```

Comment: Put a `DoEvents` between those lines.

Comment: @braX Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this after seeing your comment but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Then there must be some other issue in your other code you didnt include.

Comment: @braX I just tried creating a new file and it still doesn't work somehow. All the code in this new file are in the update above.

Comment: Oh you are using WinAPI? There's no need for that... you just need a loop with a doevents in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this instead:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  Dim dt as Date

  dt = DateAdd("s", 2, Now) ' 2 seconds
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture 2").IncrementLeft 1000

  Do Until Now > dt
    DoEvents
  Loop

  ' more stuff here after the waiting is done
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture 2").IncrementLeft 2000

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. However, when I am trying to test this with a small interval (replace 2 with 0.25, for example), it seems like the smallest actual interval as it runs is about 0.5 seconds. Are there any ways to further reduce this interval, or it's just a hardware issue?

Comment: Possible, but a bit more complex - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951860/vba-string-with-milliseconds-to-date

Comment: The link seems to be formatting and converting a string to a number instead of dealing with Date (or did I misunderstood?)......While I made another update using WinAPI GetTickCount to deal with DoEvent loop, and now it feels like working with smaller time interval.